# How do I stop loading images in Junk mail folder in Mail.app 6.6 with Gmail

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail, spam

I have setup Mail.app to use my Gmail account. Gmail has a spam filter that works excellent for me. But I sometimes check the Junk mailbox in Mail to see if something got there by accident.
When I go through the messages the images in those messages get loaded anyway as the message is placed by Gmail in the Spam folder (which is linked to the Junk mailbox) but Mail.app does not mark it as Junk and therefore loads the images.
If I manually mark the message as Junk, Mail stops loading the images.

How do I make Mail to mark the messages in Gmail's Spam folder to be marked as Junk, forcing it to not load the images?

Answer (score 1):

You have to "map" the Gmail folders to match what happens in Mail.app.

- Open Preferences in Mail.app
- Go to Accounts and select your Gmail account
- Click the "Advanced" tab
- Enter [Gmail] (yes, with the brackets) into the 'IMAP Path Prefix' field
- Close the window and Save changes to the Account.

[image: Gmail Advanced Setup]

Comment: Changed the path prefix and Mail is suddenly `Not Responding` in the activity monitor. It does have a higher CPU count, so it's doing something. What does changing the path prefix actually do?

Comment: Mail is done panicking now, but even after a restart of the app I don't get to see all my mail. Just my Inbox and my drafts. Even my Sent folder is empty.